# OTF fonts in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts

I downloaded Lato fonts from the Lato website (specifically version 2.015) and installed them onto my machine (Windows 10). Yet InDesign still says that I am missing many Lato fonts:
[image]

But they're definitely on my computer:

[image]

The only thing I can think of is that maybe I didn't install the OTF versions (they had .ttf file extensions). But I don't understand why that would make a difference.

Comment: Not an answer, but InDesign indeed makes a difference between "TTF" and "OTF" versions of similar named fonts. However, since "the newest Lato fonts in TrueType-​​flavored Open­Type for­mat (.ttf)" appear to be the correct type (the extension being "TTF" is not a problem), you should be able to replace them using that same dialog. Perhaps it's merely a version number conflict – InDesign is wary of that as well.

Comment: You were correct that it was a version number conflict. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but I must have installed a different version than the latest one. I re-deleted, re-downloaded, and re-installed, and it seems to be working now. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: Follow up: your answer was 100% correct for every version of Lato except for this one. I have no idea how to respond to this. It just says Lato Medium Italic, which I successfully reinstalled, but has a bracket at the end of it. https://i.imgur.com/9KODrDk.jpg